# Is the term sighaar as-Sahaba agreed upon among hadith scholars?

Tags: history, uloom-al-hadith, sahaba, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

Often we find in books of hadith scholars and historians (biographers) the expression that a certain narrator was among sighar as-Sahaba صغار الصحابة (maybe one could translate it small Sahabi). From the few examples I've encountered I'd assume that it refers to Sahaba who were very young when the prophet () died.

My question is, is this term well defined and agreed upon among scholars of jarh and ta'adil (if so consider quoting the definition) or are there different definitions?